# Explicitly evaluating powers of a sum of non-commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, binomial-theorem

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-commuting linear operators on an $n-$dimensional vector space $V$ with fixed canonical basis $(e_j)$, such that $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is a projector into the basis element $e_j$.

Consider the sum $s=e_1+...+e_n$. Clearly $B(s)=e_j$, and assume $A(s)=0$.

I'm curious whether the expression $(A-B)^k(s)$ can be explicitly evaluated for any integer $k$ in terms of $e_j$ and the columns $C_j=A(e_j)$. The cases $k=1$ and $k=2$ are trivial: $$A(s)-B(s)=-e_j, \\ (A-B)^2(s)=A^2(s)-AB(s)-BA(s)+B^2(s)=0-A(e_j)-0+B(s)=e_j-C_j.$$ Of course as $[A,B]\ne 0$ the generalized binomial theorem doesn't hold, but is there another way to compute this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed expression you could use to evaluate it when $k \geq 2$, but it's not pretty: $$ (A - B)^k(s) = (-1)^k \left( e_j - \sum_{i=0}^{k-2}(B - A)^i (C_j) \right).$$
(If you want to prove the above relationship, you can do it with induction, noting that $ (A-B)^{k+1}(s) = (A - B) (A - B)^{k}(s)$).

After playing with this expression, I don't think you'll be able to compute $(A-B)^k(s)$ in terms of only $e_j$ and $C_j$. The reason is because of that nasty summation term, $\left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-2}(B - A)^i \right)C_j$. This summation term will have summands like $A^{k-2} (C_j)$ and $(ABA) (C_j)$. There's just no getting around these terms.

I think the best way to evaluate an expression like this is probably iteratively, but it seems like you want a closed-form evaluation for any $k$, which I don't think is in the cards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I played around with this myself, and I think the best thing to hope for is to eliminate the dependency on $B$ and remain with some polynomial depending on the form of $A^k$. Do you think this is still too optimistic?

Comment: Once you eliminate all terms of the form $...A$, you are left with $2^{k-1}$ terms. If you cut all strings $B...B$ down to $B$, then all terms look either like $BA^{c_1}BA^{c_2}B...B$, or like $A^{c_1}BA^{c_2}B...B$. Now consider that for all integers $m$ we have $BA^mB=\alpha B$ for some real $\alpha$ and multiply the expression $(A-B)^k(s)$ by $v_j^T$ on the left. Then, it easy to see by appropriately grouping the factors that every term must be of the form $$\text{some scalar}\cdot v_j^T A^mv_j.$$Please feel free to tell me if you are not convinced by this argument...

Comment: Your idea here is very good, but I'm not quite convinced, because even after cutting the $B...B$ terms down to $B$, the terms you get don't always have a $B$ on the right hand side (or the left hand side).  Consider the term $ABA$, which will show up when $k \geq 5$. That term isn't amenable to your simplification. I think your argument here is close to a really neat simplification but there's still some edge cases left to work out.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Are you referring to an entire term $ABA$? In that case, $(AB)A(s)=0$, so we are free to ignore its contribution - in fact, that is what I referred to when I said to eliminate all terms of the form $...A$. If you mean a string $...ABA...$, then I believe it is covered in the rough argument above.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were referring to a way to simplify the summation term $\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} (B-A)^{i} C_j$, but I see now that you were referring to the original $(A - B)^k (s)$. I need some time to think about your argument more, then I'll get back to you.

Comment: You know what, I think you're right! I think you could completely eliminate $B$ and be left with just a polynomial having coefficients $A^k$ and scalar terms.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your input, it was helpful :) (P.S. my upvote won't show for some silly reason related to my reputation, but it's there).